# call paintcomponent for a jpanel in jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have a `JFrame` with a `JPanel` on it (`JPanel` is private in `JFrame`). Now I want to override `JPanel` by using `paintComponent` method.

How can I do that?

Comment: A bit unclear. Could you please post a sample code?

Comment: please get your technical vocabulary right: it's _extend_ a class and _override_ a method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your instance of `JPanel`, (assuming you're doing it this way), do this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
       // paint code
    }
};
```

The other alternative is to create a `private class` which **extends** `JPanel`. 
For example:

```
public class OuterClass{
    // fields, constructors, methods etc..

    private class MyPanel extends JPanel{   
       // fields, constructors, methods etc..

       @Override
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
          // paint code
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

not clear from your question, but I think that [nothing complicated override paintComponent for Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), please avoid to use method `paint()` for [Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), use only `paintComponent()`